# Can all sanctions imposed by Trump administration be removed by Biden?

Tags: united-states, president, iran, middle-east, sanctions

Secretary Pompeo has recently announced some more [sanctions](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-iran-nuclear-usa/us-imposes-new-sanctions-on-iranian-foundations-in-last-days-of-trump-term-idUSKBN29I24N) on Iranian Astan Qods foundation. It seems that Biden wants to  return to [JCPOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Comprehensive_Plan_of_Action) and he should remove sanctions to be able to negotiate with Islamic Republic.

My questions:

- Given that both chambers are blue, can Biden remove all sanctions as soon as he enters the White House?
- If so, what's the point of imposing such late sanctions by Trump administration, when they won't last long?

Comment: It never happens, cause the problem of the IS with Iran is not nukes, they have problem with an entity named IRI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Executive actions can be changed by Biden without consulting Congress. So, for example the restrictions on travel from mainly Muslim countries was done by executive order.  This order can be reversed on Jan 20th.

Legislation passed in the last four years can't be repealed except by Congress, and repeal bills can be filibustered in the Senate.

So, for example the Defense Appropriation bill contains a clause

> Imposition of Sanctions.--Not later than 30 days after the date
> of the enactment of this Act, the President shall impose five or more
> of the sanctions described in section 235 of the Countering America's
> Adversaries Through Sanctions Act (22 U.S.C. 9529) with respect to each
> person that knowingly engaged in the acquisition of the S-400 air
> defense system referred to in subsection (b).

The President (whoever that may be) can't remove that requirement for sanctions against Turkey and there is a minimum time of 1 year before the sanctions can be removed. It can be changed by repeal (however unlikely that may be).

While the President can change an executive order, he/she can't always reverse the effects of that order. If the President had ordered a forest to be cut down, reversing the order won't make the trees grow back!  Reversing the sanctions on Iran won't immediately restore trust in the USA by the Iranian government.

In the case of Iran, there are more than one sanctions regime in operation.  Removing Trumps sanctions won't remove all sanctions from Iran, many of which date back to 1979.

The point is to send a message.  It also forces action from Biden, which can be a route to attack him in the future. It is easier to find fault in actions than in inactions.

Comment: "trust in the USA in the Iranian government"?  Surely you're joking?  Would have been a good answer if not for that.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use irony now?

Comment: "Reversing the sanctions on Iran won't immediately restore trust in the USA in the Iranian government." Replace one of the "in"s with "by" to reduce ambiguity?? You pick which one...

Comment: @James K: Only if you somehow indicate that you are doing so, otherwise some of us are likely to take statements at face value :-)